# how to filter array in typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, filter

How to filter array in TypeScript. I tryed this

```
    findAllPersonsNotVisited():Observable<Person[]> {

    var rightNow = new Date();
    var res = rightNow.toISOString().slice(0,10).replace(/-/g,"-");




    return this.db.list('person/' + res)
        **.filter(
          person => person.isVisitor === false
        )**
        .do(console.log)
        .map(Person.fromJsonList);

}
```

And after that this

```
    ngOnInit() {
  this.allPersonsIsVisited = this.allPersons.filter(
          person => person.isVisited === false);
}
```

and array always is empty. Please tell me what i must do

Comment: that looks more or less ok. are you sure there's something in the allPersons array to begin with?

Comment: Yes, becouse if I dont use filter I see all persons. But with filter I see nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not subscribing to the **Observable**, use the below code

```
this.serviceName.
    findAllPersonsNotVisited
        .subscribe((data) => {this.allPersons = data},
                             (error)=> console.log(error),
                            (completion) => this.filterData());
```

using a private method to extract the required result with help of lodash

```
private filterData() {
    this.allPersons.forEach((person)=>{
        let p1=_.find(person,{isVisted : false});
        if(!_.isEmpty(p1)) this.allPersonsIsVisited.push(p1);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify the real JavaScript type (not the TypeScript type) of `person.isVisited`. Probably it's not boolean and the comparison using `===` always returns false. For example the generated JS code is trying to compare `0 === false`. You can also try to replace `===` with `==`.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) about `===`: The identity operator returns true if the operands are strictly equal with no type conversion.